# GASを使用してメールを送信するとブロックされてしまう

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

はじめて利用させていただきます。
よろしくお願いいたします。

スプレットシートにて管理しているメールアドレスにGoogleAppScriptを使用して
メールを一斉送信するスクリプトを使用しております。
（メール送信には　`MailApp.sendEmail`　を使用）

こちら以前使っていたGsuiteアカウントでは特に不具合なく送信ができていたのですが
全く違うGsuiteアカウントにて全く同じ管理方法のスプレットシートとスクリプトを使用して
同じようにメールの一斉送信を行った場合、メールがブロックされてしまいます。

Googleの規定にて送信の上限や外部リンクの有無で迷惑メールとして扱われてしまう可能性もあると見かけましたので
ある程度の改善も行ったのですがやはり改善されません。
以下送信時の各種条件
送信するメールアドレス数：計100件未満
cc数：1通あたり3件
外部リンク：GoogleサポートのURL以外排除

また、以前使っていたアカウントと今のアカウントの違いとしては
前アカウント：特権管理者権限あり　GCP有料版使用
現アカウント：特権管理者権限はないがそれ以外は同じ権限　GCP無料版
位かと思われます。
これらの条件差でメールはブロックされるものでしょうか。
またその他ブロックされる理由等思い当たりますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いたします。

Comment: 無料アカウントの場合の、１日の送信メール件数の上限が１００件に設定されているせいではないですか？　１件のメールでCcの宛先が３つある場合、ToとCcで４つの宛先に送られる訳ですから、４件とカウントされるはず。　そういうメールは２５件で上限に達します。

有料版と無料版だと、無料のほうが制限が厳しいです。
スーパーで、無料試食で食べられるソーセージの数と、お金を出して手に入れられるソーセージの数の上限を考えてみましょう。

Comment: ＞Fumu７さん　”１件のメールでCcの宛先が３つある場合、ToとCcで４つの宛先に送られる訳ですから、４件とカウントされるはず。　”　なるほど。Ccも宛先として換算されるのですね。。。となると有料版への変更or２５件位で止めての再度スクリプトをやり直す仕組みに変更するのが良さそうですね。アドバイスいただき誠にありがとうございました！